# Is there a better way of conditionally render child RenderFragments?

Tags: razor, blazor

When I want to conditionally render a component's child RenderFragment, I cannot use a conditional block directly within the component's tags, as this will result in an `RZ9996: Unrecognized child content error`:

```
@* Not allowed *@
<MudTable Items="myItems">
    @if (showTitle)
    {
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudText>My Table</MudText>
        </ToolBarContent>
    }
</MudTable>
@code {
    bool showTitle;
}
```

I need to define a delegate in the code and conditionally pass it as an argument:

```
<MudTable Items="myItems"
          ToolBarContent="@(showTitle ? GetTitle : null)">
</MudTable>
@code {
    bool showTitle;
    private RenderFragment GetTitle => (__builder) =>
    {
        <MudText>My Table</MudText>
    };
}
```

Is there a method to declare the markup directly in Razor syntax without having to rely on a delegate defined in the code block?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  In you first code block the Razor compiler can't find a default `ChildContent` render fragment to assign the enclosed block to,